# Sending an array of strings from VBA to a C++ DLL, then iterating through those strings

Tags: c++, vba, excel, dll

I am making a C++ DLL to allow for serial communication in Excel. It is working for the most part, but I am hung up on string arrays in VBA. This specific function of my DLL should take in an (array of char*, integer representing their length, a pointer to the beginning of a double array where I will stored parsed data for each string, and an integer representing how many doubles are in each line (numRows))

Here is the DLL code.

```
//first read a lines from the serial port and then parse it into dataArray, does this until there is no data in buffer or array is full
//returns how many rows that it read
DLL_EXPORT int WINAPI parseAllLinesFromSerialPort(char* lineBuff, int bufferLength, double* dataArray, int numRows) {
    int currentRow = 0;
    bufferAvailable = true; //it is first assumed that there is available data to be read, this is checked down the line, if false the functions return
    while((bufferAvailable) && (currentRow < numRows)) {
         parseLine((lineBuff + (currentRow*bufferLength)), bufferLength, (dataArray + (currentRow*numColumns)));
         if (bufferAvailable) {
               currentRow++;
         }
    }
    return currentRow;
}
```

So the double array part works just fine if I just pass the first string, however, if I try to send the next string each time, it simply crashes when I first call the DLL function (I believe this is where it crashes). Am I not iterating through the string array right, is it not the size I think it is, or in the following VBA have I initialized the array wrong or passed it into the DLL wrong?

This is the VBA code.
See specifically the collectAllDataAvailable() function, as this is the one that calls that DLL function.

```vb
Option Explicit

'reads all avialable lines from serial
Public Declare Function parseAllLinesFromSerialPort _
Lib "C:\Users\alexw\Desktop\Parsing\bin\Debug\ArduinoTesterDll.dll" _
(line As String, ByVal length As Integer, dataArray As Double, ByVal numRows As Long) As Long


'Global Variables
Public currentDataRow As Long 'keeps track of the currentRow that data is being read into
Public Const numRows As Long = 100 'number of rows grabed at a time by collectAllDataAvailable
Public Const stringLength As Integer = numRows * 8

'selects then clears the dataCollection
Public Sub clearDataCollectionAndBuffers()
    'clears the whole right side under row 5 to column AZ
    Main.Range("K6:AZ1048575").Select
    Selection.ClearContents
    'Clears the Serial Window
    Main.dataBox.Text = ""
    'sets the next data read row to begin at 6
    currentDataRow = 6
    'clears the serial buffers
    Call clearSerialPort 'See Module 1
End Sub

'collects all rows available, up to 46000, currently 1000 lines, set above as a global numRows
Public Sub collectAllDataAvailable()
    Dim J As Integer ' increment variables for a for loop
    Dim I As Integer

    Dim startingCol As Integer 'for K this would be 11
    startingCol = 11

    Dim numCol As Long 'how many data point (3 for #,#,#)
    Dim numRowsRead As Long 'how many rows are read (were available)
    numCol = getNumColumns 'see module 2 for function getNumColumns

    Dim arrayLength As Long
    arrayLength = (numCol * numRows) 'grabs global numRows lines at a time if available, this is a maximum

    Dim dataArray() As Double
    ReDim dataArray(0 To (arrayLength - 1)) As Double

    Dim lineArray() As String * stringLength 'global, needs to be big enough hold each row od data
    ReDim lineArray(0 To (numRows - 1)) As String * stringLength

    numRowsRead = parseAllLinesFromSerialPort(lineArray(0), Len(lineArray(0)), dataArray(0), numRows)

    For J = 0 To (numRowsRead - 1)
        Main.dataBox.Text = Main.dataBox.Text & lineArray(J)
        For I = 0 To (numCol - 1)
            Main.Cells((J + currentDataRow), (I + startingCol)).Value = dataArray(I + (J * numCol))
        Next I
    Next J

    currentDataRow = currentDataRow + numRowsRead
    'only stoped in Main sheets code for stopDataButton
    If Main.dataCollectionActive Then Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"), "collectAllDataAvailable"
End Sub

Public Sub writeCommand()
    Dim bytesWritten As Integer
    bytesWritten = writeToSerialPort(Main.Range("Command").Value, Len(Main.Range("Command").Value))
End Sub
```

When I pass just a string, and do not worry about an array and iterating through it. Then the VBA and excel works fine (other than the fact that I loose other strings I want to keep as they are written over each other each time I call parseLine in the DLL with the one string that I have). I want to be able to save each string that I am parsing into the Double array so that when I return from the DLL I have all the strings that I parsed so that I can display them. However when I tried to implement this array of strings, Excel now simply crashes upon the attempt to call the parseAllLinesFromSerialPort function. Any idea what I am doing wrong here? Also I will take any other suggestions to clean up my current code as I am doing this project for a job.

Comment: http://www.cpearson.com/excel/sizestring.htm

Comment: this link is where I found the *length notation for defining strings. I would like to be able to specify the length of each string in the array, this is why I did this, but you may be correct in that I have done this incorrectly with the array. I do know it works for a single string.

Comment: I am unsure of how I would use the stringName = String(0,#) with an array or if that is what I should use.

Comment: Also if I simply remove the *stringLength the Len(stringArray(0)) is 0, when watched in excel